# how to create a fixed js slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

i have a java slider im building for works new website and am having trouble getting it to be a fixed size, it resizes it self to the size of the image. how can i make this relative?

```js
<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Slider</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<body>

<h2 class="w3-center">Greenscape slider</h2>

<div class="w3-content" style="max-width:400px;position:relative">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://s585624729.websitehome.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/cropped-Profile-Pic-1-1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://s585624729.websitehome.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Roiente-Connect-1.png" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://s585624729.websitehome.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/How-solar-works-1.png" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://s585624729.websitehome.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Greenscape-Logo-1.png" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://s585624729.websitehome.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Trevor-Sheldrick1-1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  
  <a class="w3-btn-floating" style="position:absolute;top:45%;left:0;" onclick="plusDivs(-1)"><</a>
  <a class="w3-btn-floating" style="position:absolute;top:45%;right:0" onclick="plusDivs(1)">></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to update your code like given below...

```
    <div class="w3-content" style="width:50%;height:50%;position:absolute;float:left;left:0;">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://s585624729.websitehome.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/cropped-Profile-Pic-1-1.jpg" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://s585624729.websitehome.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Roiente-Connect-1.png" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://s585624729.websitehome.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/How-solar-works-1.png" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://s585624729.websitehome.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Greenscape-Logo-1.png" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://s585624729.websitehome.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Trevor-Sheldrick1-1.jpg" style="width:100%;height:100%;">

      <a class="w3-btn-floating" style="position:absolute;top:45%;left:0;" onclick="plusDivs(-1)"><</a>
      <a class="w3-btn-floating" style="position:absolute;top:45%;right:0" onclick="plusDivs(1)">></a>
    </div>
```